# Error installing dagitty and ggdag packages in R

Tags: r, package, install.packages

When I try to install the following packages:

```
install.packages("dagitty")
install.packages("ggdag")
```

I get the following message in the console:

```
> install.packages("dagitty")
also installing the dependency ‘V8’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions
  are later:
        binary source needs_compilation
V8       3.0.2  3.2.0              TRUE
dagitty  0.2-2  0.3-0             FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) install.packages("ggdag")
Error in install.packages : Unrecognized response “install.packages("ggdag")”
```

If I click enter, this continues for 5 min or so and in the end I get an error again. Do you know what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to install V8 first. Since I assume you use OSX, you can install it via homebrew: `brew install v8` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install both packages at the same time? The first line `install.packages("dagitty")` tries to evaluate, but it requires a manual response on what to do with respect to the binaries. When that prompt occurs, R tries to fit in the second line you submitted. That line is not a valid answer to the prompt. Install them one at a time and see if that works.